# Prometheus client library for ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, prometheus

I've found a lot of NuGet packages for ASPNetCore-targeted Prometheus metrics exporters, but I can't find a single one for the "old good" ASP.NET WebAPI.

I need a client library somewhat similar to Prometheus.Client or prometheus-net that can register the end-point among other WebAPI controllers and expose the metrics gathered in different places in a standard Prometheus-compatible format.
DI, attributes and other Asp.Net goodies are welcome, but not must.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus already has a .Net Framework package.

See https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net

> Nuget package for ASP.NET Web API middleware on .NET Framework: prometheus-net.NetFramework.AspNet
>
> Install-Package prometheus-net.NetFramework.AspNet